# cookie does not work in file based browsering

Tags: session-cookies

I use vs2019 on win10 to develop my webapi application.
In order to debug my java-script code, I would like open
a separate chrome page and open an independent page of
"d:/dir/dir/index.html" along with a couple of javascript calling
webapi (debug mode).

In this situation, Server always response cookie with new session-Id each webapi call,
while the normal https://localhost:44386/api/xxx works fine.